# how to set icon FCM push notification in ionic2

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I have success, make local notification and  set the notification icon and onclickevent in notification  it is works, but how to make like that in Push notification in FCM, i some question from the only simple script i have.

```
async onNotification() {
//this.getToken();
try {
    FCMPlugin.onNotification((data) => {
        alert(data.message);
    });
}
catch (e) {
    alert("Error 2 : " +e);  
}
}
```

**1. Where can I set the notification icon?**,
**2. Where can I set an action when the notification is clicked?**
**3. When the App is in the foreground, sometimes the notification is not displayed, but when I close the App the notification appears**